# Selecting rows in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have data as below. Each patient has a unique id, drug indicates prescribed medication.

```
Id drug
1   abc
1   ghi
2   abc
2   cde
2   def
3   ghi
3   klm
```

I would like to see what drugs are prescribed for patients with "ghi" in SQL. The result should be some what like this.

Id drug

1   abc

1   ghi

3   ghi

3   klm

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Thank you.

Comment: By which we mean code, not drugs

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT id, drug FROM (SELECT id FROM Patients WHERE drug = 'ghi') AS T INNER JOIN Patients AS P ON T.id = P.id
```

That will get the list of all patients who have 'ghi' and from that list return a list of ids and drugs prescribed to those patients.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention your table name. I guessed it as **prescription**.

**Your expected query:**

```
select * from prescription where id in 
(select id from prescription where drug='ghi')
```

Here is how I have done it.

**Database Schema**

```
create table prescription
(
  id int,
  drug varchar(100)
);
insert into prescription(id, drug) values(1, 'abc');
insert into prescription(id, drug) values(1, 'ghi');
insert into prescription(id, drug) values(2, 'cde');
insert into prescription(id, drug) values(2, 'def');
insert into prescription(id, drug) values(3, 'ghi');
insert into prescription(id, drug) values(3, 'klm');
```

**Query**

```
select * from prescription where id in 
(select id from prescription where drug='ghi')
```

**Result**

```
id  drug
1   abc
1   ghi
3   ghi
3   klm
```

If you want to test it online here is the fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a299/7/0

Comment: Glad to hear that. When a user receives a good answer to his or her question, that user has the option to "accept" an answer. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer